# Replace an item in an array?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

Trying to figure some logic and wondering if the following code will work, or if there's another way of doing this. (Just trying to find out if my logic works, might missform a bit of the code)

```
Var some1:MovieClip = mc_1;
" "
" "
Var other1:MovieClip = mc_a;
" "
" "

Var myArray = [some1, some2, some3];

Var i:uint;
Var iLength:uint = myArray.length;

For(i=0;i<iLength;i++){
    If(myArray[i] == some2){
        myArray[i] = other1;
    }
}
```

Question: will this replace 'some2' with 'other1'?

Answer (score 1):

your code should be edited: but the answer is yes if you fix short mistakes like it:

```
var some1:MovieClip = mc_1;
var other1:MovieClip = mc_a;

var myArray:Array = [some1, some2, some3];

var i:uint;
var iLength:uint = myArray.length;

for(i=0;i<iLength;i++){
    if(myArray[i] == some2){
        myArray[i] = other1;
        break;
    }
}
```

**♠  Method 2**

**Array.indexOf(Item)** returns position of **`Item`** in **`Array`** if **`Item`** exist's, otherwise returns **`-1`**

```
var some1:MovieClip = mc_1;
var other1:MovieClip = mc_a;
    
var myArray:Array = [some1, some2, some3];
if(myArray.indexOf(some1)>=0) myArray[myArray.indexOf(some1)] = other1;
```

### Edit:

**♠  Method 3**

to getting rid of **If** statement, using **splice**

```
var some1:MovieClip = mc_1;
var other1:MovieClip = mc_a;

var myArray:Array = [some1, some2, some3];
myArray.splice(myArray.indexOf(some1),1,some1);
```